# Scrollview doesn't show full content [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a problem with Scrollview on Android. The problem is showing all content in a register form.

XML Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
     >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/register_header"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_loginField"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_login"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_password"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_input_passw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_passw"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_repeatpass"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_input_passwre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_passw"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_gender"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/register_radiog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/register_radioM"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/register_gMale"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/register_radioF"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/register_gFemale"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        />

            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_age"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_input_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/register_input_termsofuse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/register_termsofuse"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/register_btSignup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="#fc9a24"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/register_btSignup"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I execute in my Android device I can't see the register_header textview.

Also when I click on one EditText, my device show keyboard, and all view is pushed up, hidding more items (email textview and edittext).

How can I solve this?

In this first image, as you can see header isn't showing. This is bad...

[image: Header not showing]

In this second image, I can scroll and see register button, this is good.

[image: I can scroll to bottom]

And in this third image, when keyboard appears and I go to top of the scrollview I can't see the register_header, the email input and email textview

[image: Email textview and edittext not showing]

How can I, fix layout position (not push up when keyboard appears) and show all content inside Scrollview.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity in your manifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Comment: Doesn't work, when I click in born date input (input before checkbox) still pushing up the layout, and also I still can't see reader_title, over email textview.  http://i.imgur.com/znZEida.png